# finding common occurence of given words in a line

Tags: python

I have a text file, each line of which contains a few of words. Now given a set of query words, i have to find the number of lines, in the file, where query words co-occur. i.e the number of lines containing two query words, number of lines containing 3 query words etc.

I tried using the following code: Note that rest(list,word) removes "word" from "list" and returns the updated list. linecount is the number of lines in raw.

```
raw=open("raw_dataset_1","r")
queryfile=open("queries","r")
query=queryfile.readline().split()
query_size=len(query)
two=0
three=0
four=0

while linecount>0:
    line=raw.readline().split()
    if query_size>=2:
        for word1 in query:
            beta=rest(query,word1)
            for word2 in beta:
                if (word1 in line) and (word2 in line):
                    two+=1
                    print line
    if (query_size>=3):
        for word3 in query:
            beta=rest(query,word3)
            for word4 in beta:
                gama=rest(beta,word4)
                for word5 in gama:
                    if (((word3 in line) and (word4 in line)) and (word5 in line)):
                        three+=1
                        print line
    linecount-=1

print two
print three
```

It works, although there is redundancy, i can divide "two" by 2 to get the required number)
Is there a better approach to do it?

Comment: @Vidit No. I want to find the lines which contains more than one query words. Eg my query is "sun tree". And i have lines "apple tree mango", "sun tree sky" and "sun moon star". Then number of lines where 2 query words co-occur is 1 i.e. "sun tree sky" (this line contains 2 of the query words)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a more general approach. Assuming `query` is a list of your query words and `raw_dataset_1` is the name of the file you are analysing, I would do something like:

```
# list containing the number of lines with 0,1,2,3... occurrances of query words.
wordcount = [0,0,0,0,0]    
for line in file("raw_dataset_1").readlines():
    # loop over each query word, see if it occurs in the given line, and just count them. 
    # The bracket inside will create a list of elements (query_word) from your query word list (query)
    # but add only those words which occur in the line (if  query_word in line). [See list comprehension]
    # E.g. if your line contain three query words those three will be in the list.
    # You are not interested in what those words are, so you just take the length of the list (len). 
    # Finally, number_query_words_found is the number of query words present in the current line of text. 
    number_query_words_found = len([query_word for query_word in query if query_word in line])  
    if number_query_words_found<5:
        # increase the line-number by one. The index corresponds to the number of query-words present
        wordcount[number_query_words_found] += 1

print "Number of lines with 2 query words: ", wordcount[2]
print "Number of lines with 3 query words: ", wordcount[3]
```

This code is not tested and can be optimized. The file will be read entirely (inefficient for larger files) and the list `wordcount` it static, should be done dynamically (to allow for any word occurrances. But something like this should work, except I misunderstood your question. For list comprehension see e.g. [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: could you please explain this line "len([query_word for query_word in query if query_word in line]) "

Comment: I am getting NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Comment: Uh sorry, the example is fixed now. It should read `for line in file("raw_dataset_1").readlines():`...

Comment: That's an O(N^2) solution: you're iterating once through the line for every word you need to check. Using sets would give an O(N) solution instead.

Comment: @Alex : Thanks a lot for the help:). This piece of code is very nice. I learnt a lot.

Comment: @rmunn: You are right, in addition to the inefficient points I pointed out. The snippet of code could be improved in various directions, but for a python beginner it might suffice.

Comment: Using sets is also better because this_set.intersection(that_set) is easier to understand than a list comprehension, in my experience. At any rate, there are now two decent solutions posted that use different approaches, so he'll be able to learn from both of them.

Answer (score 2):

I would use sets for this:

```
raw=open("raw_dataset_1","r")
queryfile=open("queries","r")
query_line = queryfile.readline()
query_words = query_line.split()
query_set = set(query_words)
query_size = len(query_set)  # Note that this isn't actually used below

for line in raw: # Iterating over a file gives you one line at a time
    words = line.strip().split()
    word_set = set(words)
    common_set = query_set.intersection(word_set)
    if len(common_set) == 2:
        two += 1
    elif len(common_set) == 3:
        three += 1
    elif len(common_set) == 4:
        four += 1
```

Of course, instead of just counting the occurrences, you might want to save the line to a results file, or anything else. But this should give you the general idea: using sets will simplify your logic immensely.

Comment: @munn : Thanks a lot:). Yeah i get the idea used here